# Django foreign key question

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

All,

i have the following model defined,

```
  class header(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
     created_by = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

     def __unicode__(self):
       return self.id()

 class criteria(models.Model):
     details =   models.CharField(max_length = 255)
     headerid = models.ForeignKey(header)

     def __unicode__(self):
       return self.id()

 class options(models.Model):
     opt_details =   models.CharField(max_length = 255)
     headerid = models.ForeignKey(header)

     def __unicode__(self):
       return self.id()
```

AND IN MY VIEWS I HAVE

```
           p= header(title=name,created_by=id)
           p.save()
```

Now the data will be saved to header table .My question is that for this id generated in header table how will save the data to criteria and options table..Please let me know..

Thanks..

Comment: Please Use UpperCase Names for Classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your:

```
p= header(title=name,created_by=id)
p.save()
```

You can now:

```
c=criteria(details='some details', headerid=p)
c.save()
o=options(opt_details='more details', headerid=p)
o.save()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of `<related>_set` query managers, it's clearer and shorter than constructing and saving objects in separate operations.

```
h = header.objects.create(title=name,created_by=id)
c = h.criteria_set.create(details='some details')
o = h.options_set.create(opt_details='more details')
```

And some offtopic: please, start class names from uppercase letter, it really makes code easier to read.